# How to get the following gradual shadow on edges in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, shadow

In some 3d scenes, I found the gradual shadow near edges of objects. It'll emphasize edges clearly between two faces. How can we realize this effect? Is this a shadow technology or light reflecting tech?

example image:
[image: example image]

Answer (score 0):

This effect is called [Ambient Occlusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_occlusion). Three.js doesn't offer this "out of the box", but there are several ways to implement it yourself. See also [this related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914697/ambient-occlusion-in-threejs).